# Django: Getting results from multiple joined tables

Tags: django

I have 3 tables flotation has many lightresidues has many compositions.

I'm wanting to make a view for each flotation which can access a list of light residues and a list of associated compositions. There are only ever 2-3 light residues to each flotation and the same for compositions, so manageable.

I can get a flotation record and its referenced light residues, but I'm having trouble passing the lightresidue_id to get the compositions. [n.b. I know lightresidue.id is the Django way of doing things, but I opt for this way]

The view code is as follows, I've hard coded for `lightresidue.lightresidue_id = 17` which works, but how do I substitute this for the `lightresidue.lightresidue_id = composition.lightresidue_id`.

```
def botanyoverview(request, flotation_id):
    flotation = get_object_or_404(Flotation, pk=flotation_id)
    lightresidue = LightResidue.objects.filter(flotation_id__flotation_id=flotation_id)
    # composition = Composition.objects.filter(lightresidue.lightresidue_id)
    composition = Composition.objects.filter(lightresidue_id=17)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/botanyoverview.html',
    {
        'flotation':flotation,
        'lightresidue':lightresidue,
        'composition':composition,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by chaining the compositions of all the `lightresidue` using itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

def botanyoverview(request, flotation_id):
    flotation = get_object_or_404(Flotation, pk=flotation_id)
    lightresidue = LightResidue.objects.filter(flotation_id__flotation_id=flotation_id)
    queryset = []
    for i in lightresidue:
        queryset += Composition.objects.filter(lightresidue_id = i.lightresidue_id)

    composition = chain.from_iterable(queryset)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/botanyoverview.html',
    {
        'flotation':flotation,
        'lightresidue':lightresidue,
        'composition':composition,
    })
```

the `lightresidue` may contain one or more objects and so here i am getting all the `compositions` associated with each `lightresidue` sepearately and combining them using `itertools`.

Comment: I'll give this a go, but surely there is a way to do multiple inner joins as you would in sql?

Comment: It works in the shell, but not in the html 
          {% for composition in composition.all %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ composition.composition_id}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

Comment: composition.all will not work since it is not an queryset.<br/>Try this:<br/>{% for i in composition %}{{i.id}}{% endfor %}

Comment: yes I just realised, it is a itertools.chain object, so how do I get this object to display in the html?

Comment: {% for i in composition %}{{i.id}}{% endfor %}

Comment: I used `composition = queryset` rather than `composition = chain.from_iterable(queryset)` If you update your answer I'll accept it, thanks for your help.

Comment: `queryset` will contain the list of the results. so i used `chain.from_iterables` to get all the individual elements and make into an single list. Anyways if you got your workdone its good.